# How can I insert into laravel pivot table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**I have 3 tables:**

```
stations (id,station_name) 
products (id,product_name)
product_station (station_id,product_id)
```

**Station Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['station_name'];
public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

**Product Model**

```
 protected $fillable = ['product_name'];

public function stations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Station::class);
}
```

> I already have inserted stations and products and i want to insert
>   station with it's own product using into Pivot table

**AdminProductStationcontroller**

```
public function create()
    {
        $station = Station::pluck('station_name','id')->all();

        $products = Product::pluck('product_name','id')->all();

        return view('admin.product_stations.create',compact('station','products'));
    }
```

> I think there is error in store function below

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $station = new Station();

        $product = new Product();

        $station->save();

        $station->products()->attach($product);

        return redirect('/admin/product_stations');
     }
```

**So i have got this error**

*(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `product_station` (`product_id`, `station_id`) values (, 25))*

Answer (score 2):

`attach()` expects a single or an array of ids of the related Model implying that the Model should have been created beforehand.

What you're looking for is the `save(Model)` method.

```
$station->products()->save($product);
```

More on the above in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You should firstly save

```
$station = new Station();
$station->save();

$product = new Product();
$product->save();
```

then
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

```
$station->products()->attach($product->id);
```

OR

You can try to save like so

```
$station->products()->save($product);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Post Model
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' =>'required',
            'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'live_demo' =>'required'
        ]);

          $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());   
            $image_resize->resize(1600,1066);
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
            }
            //$image->move('storage/uploads/post',$imagename);
            $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/post/'.$imagename);
        }else{
            $imagename = "default.png";
        }

         $post = new Post();
        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
        $post->image = $imagename;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->price = $request->price;
        $post->live_demo = $request->live_demo;
        if(isset($request->status))
            {
                $post->status =true;
            }else
            {
                $post->status = false;
            }
        $post->is_approved = true;
        $post->save();
        $post->categories()->attach($request->categories);
        $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);

        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Save:)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
    }

// Pivot table create category_post column create   category_id, post_id.
// Pivot table create post_tag, and column create post_id, and tag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $station->products()->sync($request->products , false);
```

Comment: Does this solve OPs problem? Please provide more details to support your code.